# Determining if two given propositions are logically equivalent

Tags: logic, relations, real-numbers

I'm currently taking a coursera mathematics course (Introduction to Mathematical Thinking), and I encountered the following question in one of the problem sets:

$(x>0)∧(x≤10)$ means $0≤x≤10$, for any real number $x$ . True or false?

I chose "true", but the answer given after I received feedback was "false". Can someone please explain why the above statement is false? Or was the answer given after feedback incorrect?

Comment: On the left you have $x>0$ but on the right you wrote $x≥0$.

Comment: Elaborating further on the above comment, if the difference noted there is just a typo from OP, then yes, the statement would be true by definition

Comment: @ Dark Rebellion, it wasn't a typo. Thank you very much, @ lulu, now it is clear to me. The error in my reasoning was assuming that $x>0$ and $x≥0$ are logically equivalent. Although $x>0$ implies that $x≥0$, the converse is not true.